# How to call a div height in jQuery and set it into the css of another div dynamically (upon window resizing)?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am currently trying to set the CSS height of a div, to the same as another div's height using jQuery.

I have been able to create variable based off of the target div's height, and apply this to the CSS of the relevant div, but for some reason the applied height is static (it is not resizing with the other div, and has a static value in the html "style=" section of inspect element.

Here is my code:

```
var headheight = $('.tag-6 .site #custom-header-media .rt-slider-wrapper .slide-item .rt-wrapper').outerHeight();
$( ".slide-item" ).css('height': headheight)
```

Any suggestions?
Thanks a lot

Comment: `$(window).resize(function(){...})`, This function will execute whenever the window is being resized.

Comment: @Ibnelaiq Thanks a lot!!